# Repeating a function 1000 times and saving each iteration result in a list

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, iteration, histogram

I have tried to simulate some event-onsets and predictors for an experiment. I have two predictors (circles and squares). The stimuli ('events') take 1 second and the ISI (interstimulus interval) is 8 seconds. I am also interested in both contrasts against baseline (circles against baseline; squares against baseline). In the end, I am trying to run the function that I have defined (simulate_data_fixed, n=420 is a paramater that is fixed) for 1000, at each iteration I would like to calculate an efficiency score in the end and store the efficiency scores in a list.

```
def simulate_data_fixed_ISI(N=420):

    dg_hrf = glover_hrf(tr=1, oversampling=1)
    
    # Create indices in regularly spaced intervals (9 seconds, i.e. 1 sec stim + 8 ISI)
    stim_onsets = np.arange(10, N - 15, 9)
    stimcodes = np.repeat([1, 2], stim_onsets.size / 2)  # create codes for two conditions
    np.random.shuffle(stimcodes)  # random shuffle
    stim = np.zeros((N, 1))

    c = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])

    # Fill stim array with codes at onsets
    for i, stim_onset in enumerate(stim_onsets):
        stim[stim_onset] = 1 if stimcodes[i] == 1 else 2
    
    stims_A = (stim == 1).astype(int)
    stims_B = (stim == 2).astype(int)

    reg_A = np.convolve(stims_A.squeeze(), dg_hrf)[:N]
    reg_B = np.convolve(stims_B.squeeze(), dg_hrf)[:N]
    X = np.hstack((np.ones((reg_B.size, 1)), reg_A[:, np.newaxis], reg_B[:, np.newaxis]))
    dvars = [(c[i, :].dot(np.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(X))).dot(c[i, :].T))
             for i in range(c.shape[0])]
    eff = c.shape[0] / np.sum(dvars)
    return eff
```

However, I want to run this entire chunk 1000 times and store the 'eff' in an array, etc. so that later on I want to display them as a histogram. How ı can do this?

Comment: Please edit your question to fix the indentation, but it seems all the above code is related to `simulate_data_fixed_ISI` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems to boil down to:

> I am trying to run the function that I have defined for 1000, at each iteration I would like to calculate an efficiency score in the end and store the efficiency scores in a list

I guess "the function that I have defined" is the `simulate_data_fixed_ISI` in your question?

Then you can simply run it 1000 times using a basic for loop, and add the results into a list:

```
def simulate_data_fixed_ISI(N=420):

    dg_hrf = glover_hrf(tr=1, oversampling=1)
    
    # Create indices in regularly spaced intervals (9 seconds, i.e. 1 sec stim + 8 ISI)
    stim_onsets = np.arange(10, N - 15, 9)
    stimcodes = np.repeat([1, 2], stim_onsets.size / 2)  # create codes for two conditions
    np.random.shuffle(stimcodes)  # random shuffle
    stim = np.zeros((N, 1))

    c = np.array([[0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])

    # Fill stim array with codes at onsets
    for i, stim_onset in enumerate(stim_onsets):
        stim[stim_onset] = 1 if stimcodes[i] == 1 else 2
    
    stims_A = (stim == 1).astype(int)
    stims_B = (stim == 2).astype(int)

    reg_A = np.convolve(stims_A.squeeze(), dg_hrf)[:N]
    reg_B = np.convolve(stims_B.squeeze(), dg_hrf)[:N]
    X = np.hstack((np.ones((reg_B.size, 1)), reg_A[:, np.newaxis], reg_B[:, np.newaxis]))
    dvars = [(c[i, :].dot(np.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(X))).dot(c[i, :].T))
             for i in range(c.shape[0])]
    eff = c.shape[0] / np.sum(dvars)
    return eff


eff_results = []
for _ in range(1000):
    efficiency_score = simulate_data_fixed_ISI()
    eff_results.append(efficiency_score)
```

Now `eff_results` contains 1000 entries, each of which is a call to your function `simulate_data_fixed_ISI`

Comment: @e.erhan `eff_results` is a **list** and should have 1000 elements. Maybe every single one of those elements is an empty **array** (numpy.array), but then that's a problem with the `simulate_data_fixed_ISI` function.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you should be able just to run

```py
EFF = [simulate_data_fixed_ISI() for i in range(1000)] #1000 repeats
```

As @theonlygusti clarified, this line, `EFF`, runs your function `simulate_data_fixed_ISI()` 1000 times and put each return in the array `EFF`

**Test**

```py
import numpy as np
def simulate_data_fixed_ISI(n=1):
    """
    Returns 'n' random numbers
    """
    return np.random.rand(n)

EFF = [simulate_data_fixed_ISI() for i in range(5)]

EFF
#[array([0.19585137]),
# array([0.91692933]),
# array([0.49294667]),
# array([0.79751017]),
# array([0.58294512])]
```

Comment: Should I add this line before or after the loop? I also want to save each iterations' results in a seperate list.

Comment: @e.erhan your question seems to define a function `simulate_data_fixed_ISI ` (you should edit your question to fix indentation)  which gives you your eff. This answer `EFF = [simulate_data_fixed_ISI() for i in range(1000)]` uses your function to create a new list containing 1000 results of `simulate_data_fixed_ISI()`. You must use this answer's code outside of your function.

Comment: Do you want the function to run 1000 times or... ? See the edited answer for how I used it